# Character specific conditional check in a string

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, file

I have to read and analyse some log files using python which usually containing strings in the following desired format :

```
date Don Dez 10 21:41:41.747 2020
base hex  timestamps absolute
no internal events logged
// version 13.0.0
//28974.328957 previous log file: 21-41-41_Voltage.asc
// Measurement UUID: 9e0029d6-43a0-49e3-8708-3ec70363124c
28976.463987    LoggingString := "Log,5:45 AM, Friday, December 11, 2020,05:45:20.6,65.48,11.99,0.009843,12,0.01078,11.99,0.01114,11.99,0.01096,12,0.009984,4.595,0,1.035,0,0.1745,0,2,OM_2_1,0"
28978.600018    LoggingString := "Log,5:45 AM, Friday, December 11, 2020,05:45:22.7,65.47,11.99,0.009896,12,0.01079,11.99,0.01117,11.99,0.01097,12,0.009965,4.628,0,1.044,0,0.1698,0,2,OM_2_1,0"
```

However, sometime it occurs that files are created that have undesired formats like below :

```
date Die Jul 13 08:40:22.878 2021                                                                                                                                                                   
base hex  timestamps absolute                                                                                                                                                                   
no internal events logged                                                                                                                                                                   
// version 13.0.0                                                                                                                                                                   
//1035.595166 previous log file: 08-40-22_Voltage.asc                                                                                                                                                                   
// Measurement UUID: 2baf3f3f-300a-4f0a-bcbf-0ba5679d8be2                                                                                                                                                                   
"1203.997816    LoggingString := ""Log" 9:01 am  Tuesday     July 13    2021    09:01:58.3  24.53   13.38   0.8948  13.37   0.8801  13.37   0.89    13.37   0.9099  13.47   0.8851  4.551   0.00115 0.8165  0   0.2207  0   5   OM_3_2  1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   "0"""
"1206.086064    LoggingString := ""Log" 9:02 am  Tuesday     July 13    2021    09:02:00.4  24.53   13.37   0.8945  13.37   0.8801  13.37   0.8902  13.37   0.9086  13.46   0.8849  5.142   0.001185    1.033   0   0.1897  0   5   OM_3_2  1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   "0"""
```

OR

```
date    Mit Jun 16  10:11:43.493    2021                                                                                                                                                                    
base    hex timestamps  absolute                                                                                                                                                                            
no  internal    events  logged                                                                                                                                                                          
//  version 13.0.0                                                                                                                                                                              
//  Measurement UUID:   fe4a6a97-d907-4662-89f9-bd246aa54a33                                                                                                                                                                            
10025.661597    LoggingString   :=  """""""Log"""   12:59   PM  Wednesday   June    16  2021    12:59:01.1  66.14   0.00423 0   0.001206    0   0.001339    0   0.001229    0   0.001122    0   0.05017 0   0.01325 0   0.0643  0   0   OM_2_1_transition   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   """0"""""""
10030.592652    LoggingString   :=  """""""Log"""   12:59   PM  Wednesday   June    16  2021    12:59:06.1  66.14   11.88   0.1447  11.88   0.1444  11.88   0.1442  11.87   0.005552    11.9    0.00404 2.55    0   0.4712  0   0.09924 0   0   OM_2_1_transition   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   """0"""""""
```

Since i am only concerned with data below "// Measurement UUID " line, i am using this code to extract data from the string that is of desired format :

```
files = os.listdir(directory)
    files = natsorted(files)
    for file in files:
        base, ext = os.path.splitext(file)
        if file not in processed_files and ext == '.asc':
            print("File added:", file)
            file_path = os.path.join(directory, file)
            count = 0
            with open(file_path, 'r') as file_in:
                processed_files.append(file)
                Output_list = []  # Each string from file is read into this list
                Final = []  # Required specific data from each string is isolated & stored here
                for line in map(str.strip, file_in):
                    if "LoggingString" in line:
                        first_quote = line.index(
                            '"')  # returns the column number where " first appears in the whole string
                        last_quote = line.index('"', first_quote + 1)
                        # returns the column value where " appears last in the whole string ( end of line )
                        # print(first_quote)
                        Output_list.append(
                            line[:first_quote].split(maxsplit=1)
                            + line[first_quote + 1: last_quote].split(","),
                        )
                        Final.append(Output_list[count][7:27])
```

The undesired format contains one or more whitespaces between each string character as seen above. I guess it is because the log file generator sometime generates a non comma separate file or a comma separated file with error probably, i am not sure.

I tried to put the condition after:

```
if "LoggingString" in line :
    if ',' in line:
        first_quote = line.index('"')
        last_quote = line.index('"', first_quote + 1)
        Output_list.append(line[:first_quote].split(maxsplit=1)
                            + line[first_quote + 1: last_quote].split(","),)
                        Final.append(Output_list[count][7:27])
    else:
        raise Exception("Error in File")
```

However, this didn't serve the purpose because if in any other undesired format if there is even one ',' in the string, the program would consider it valid and process it which results in false results.

How do i ensure that after the only files that contain strings in desired format are processed and if others are processed then an error message would be print out ? What type of conditional check could be implemented here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`pandas.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) with a *regex* separator :

```
import glob
import pandas as pd

l = []
for f in glob.glob("/tmp/Log*.txt"):
    df = (pd.read_csv(f, sep=',|(?<=[\w"])\s+(?=[\w"])',
                      header=None, skiprows=6, engine="python").iloc[:, 2:28])
    df.insert(0, "filename", f.split("\\", )[-1])
    l.append(df)
    
out = pd.concat(l)
```

Output :

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response. But my file is not a .csv file. Instead it's a .asc file. Will pd.read_csv work for such files ?

Comment: Basically it can't but can you try it ?

Comment: I tried it gave an error : pandas.errors.ParserError: Expected 45 fields in line 99, saw 46. Error could possibly be due to quotes being ignored when a multi-char delimiter is used.

Comment: The good news is that `pandas.read_csv` can actually read `.asc` (logging format) files. And the bad news, it seems that you have another format of logs other than the three you shared in your question. To make sure it is the case, can you add `on_bad_lines="skip"` as a keyword argument to `pandas.read_csv` ?